# Is it possible to navigate through html document in postman using JS DOM Element method

Tags: javascript, dom, postman

and how to declare it in Postman sandbox?

I need something like this:

```
var h1Text = window.document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML;
console.log(h1Text);
```

Also I need to find something this way:

I have many  tags, and I need to find exact one. Shuld I use loop over method to find what I want Or there is a better way to get element data with requested property?

Comment: What do you mean, you want to navigate through the response from some endpoint?  Your question is very unclear, please provide more details.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: That doesn't add anything useful. What is this "html document" that you want to navigate?

Comment: I make a request to apache web server, it send a response with html document. Now I need to extract id from <a> tag contains "invoice", for example, <a href="/report/invoice.php?ID=602">

Comment: I think you are looking for a method to render the response html in a browser, after that you can use the js DOM functions. 1> try ajax in front end to get the html and render it in a web page. or 2> try to get the response from a server, i.e. use php CURL. Then generate the response to a web page.

Comment: If you have received a valid HTML document, then you can render it as @QiaoLi mentioned, then use normal means to navigate/traverse it.  If you don't want to render it for some reason, you could create a document fragment and 'render' your HTML to the fragment.  It won't appear anywhere but will be a freestanding `Document` object that supports all the standard methods such as `querySelector`, etc.

If this sounds like it will help with your problem, let me know and I can post some sample code.

Comment: T Nguyen, yes, it sounds like what I need, but I don't know how to implement it in Postman sanbox terms.

Comment: @T Nguyen I have found a clear example of what I am looking for. Here https://www.mwtestconsultancy.co.uk/postman-parsing-html-responses is stated that it is nativa JS, and postman is said to support native JS. But when I call www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp and execute this code (var responseHTML = document.createElement("html");
responseHTML.innerHTML = responseBody;), postman say "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Postman application, you want to load your response body via Cheerio library, and parse it using JavaScript.

Here's an example I've used in the past for a quick fix to one of my issues:

```
const html = cheerio(responseBody);

var results = [];

html.find('div[class="AutoGrid-cell min-w-0"] > div').each(function (i, e)
{
    results.push({
        "Item": e.children[e.children.length-3].children[0].children[0].children[0]["data"],
        "Price": e.children[e.children.length-4].children[0].attribs["value"]
    })
});
```